# Trigger repository only when repository dispatch found

Tags: github-actions

I have a scenario where I have a github workflow which triggers multiple repos on the basis of repository dispatch trigger present in the github actions of these multiple repos. But I want to put a condition in my main workflow that if repo dispatch is not found in any one of these repos that particular repo should get skipped.
Is there any way I can implement this in my main workflow?

Current implementation:

```
on: push
jobs:
  Test1:
     runs-on: [ubuntu-latest ]
     outputs:
        matrix: ${{ steps.set-matrix.outputs.matrix }}
     steps:
       - uses: actions/checkout@v2
       - id: set-matrix
         name: condition 
         run: |
           VAR=$(echo $(cat .github/workflows/ab.json)
           echo “::set-output name=matrix::$VAR”
   Test2:
      needs: Test1
      runs-on: ubuntu-latest
      strategy: 
        matrix: ${{fromJSON(needs.Test1.outputs.matrix)}}
      steps: 
         - name: Testing
           if: ${{ matrix.enabled }}
           uses: Peter-evans/repository-dispatch@v1
           with:
             token:
             repository: ${{ matrix.action }}
             client-payload: ‘{}’
```

Comment: Can you share your current implementation ? In general you can just dispatch a trigger and if nothing will be implemneted handling it - it's silently gonna do nothing.

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski current implementation is added to the question. Can you pls let me know where can I dispatch a trigger?